# Detecting tooltip event on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am using qtip2 for displaying a tooltip on checking a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" /> User

$(document).on('click', '#chk1', function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content: 'This is a test',
        show: 'click',
        hide: 'click'
    });
});
```

It detects with a basic

```
$('#chk1').qtip({
    content: 'This is a test',
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'click'
});
```

But not the other one. How can I make it work with the `$(document)` reference

Comment: Is what you have down exactly how it is in your document? For example in the first code block.

Answer (score 0):

This has been helpfull for me, don't remember where I got it from:

```
    // IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression
(function(myfunction) {

    // The global jQuery object is passed as a parameter
    myfunction(window.jQuery, window, document);

}(function($, window, document) {
    // The $ is now locally scoped 
    // Listen for the jQuery ready event on the document
    $(function() {
        // The DOM is ready!
        $(document).on('click', '#chk1', function(){
            $(this).qtip({
                content: 'This is a test',
                show: 'click',
                hide: 'click'
            });
        });

    });
    // The rest of code goes here!
}));
```

This are different moments of the loading proces of elements, jquery, etc. I'm not so much into this, but it might be of help to you.